# ¿Como cambiar Action segun condicion en Ajax url?

Tags: java, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo el siguiente sript:

```
$('a[id^=asociar-]').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var params = {
            id: parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring(8)),
            proveedorId: $('#proveedorId').val()
        };

        var asociado = $(this).find('input').val();
        var actionName = (asociado === 'False') ? 'Asociar' : 'Desasociar';

        var jsUrl = '@Url.Action("##", "Administrador")';
        $.ajax({
            url: jsUrl.replace('##', actionName),
            type: "post",
            data: params,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.flag) {
                    $("#asociar-" + params.id).removeClass("fa-square-o").addClass("fa-check-square-o");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Necesito que el ActionName sea dinamica segun la condicion, en el script no me esta funcionando el Replace dentro del ajax me genera el error:

NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:7597/**Administrador/%23%23"**

¿Alguna idea de como lograr esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en los caracteres que utilizas para reemplazar en la url.

```js
var jsUrl = '@Url.Action("##", "Administrador")';
```

El método Url.Action va a devolver un string con la url a la acción indicada, pero realiza un UrlEncode de este string para convertirlo en una url válida. Lo cual quiere decir que la url quedaría como:

```js
var jsUrl = '/Administrador/%23%23';
```

Con lo que, al realizar el replace no reemplazará nada.

Puedes probar con otros caracteres válidos en una url (como por ejemplo unos guiones) y te funcionará.

Comment: Muchas gracias, cambie los caracteres y me funciono.